# How to use mvn with GitHub actions (self-hosted runner)

Tags: maven, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am using GitHub enterprise server, so I cannot use stCarolas/setup-maven. (because it is not an verified account).
I think it is normal to pre-install maven in runner, but I am forbidden to do so by my administrators.

How should I use the mvn command?

Comment: Using a Docker image?

Comment: If java is available, consider using the [maven wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup maven in the OS by running e.g. yum (Redhat) or apt (Ubuntu) or wget (Mac) or extracting on Windows :

- name: setup maven (e.g. on Ubuntu)
  run: |
  sudo apt install maven
  mvn -version

Or you can create an action on your own repo (e.g. by cloning stCarolas/setup-maven)

The stCarolas action is fairly straightforward.
It downloads and extracts the official maven binary (after checking your OS) and then adds it to your path:

```
const downloadUrl = `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/${version}/apache-maven-${version}-bin.tar.gz`;
```

If downloading a maven binary from the internet directly to your runner is not permitted, you can get a blessed version and install it in the cache on your runner.

If you have custom runners that you will always use for java/maven builds, then you can have your OS configuration (e.g. terraform, ansible) maintain runners (or an image with Java and Maven pre-installed.  Which is fastest, but shifts maintenance to your team.